# Django complex query for OR

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm using django 1.10

I've created this query which works for me:

```
filters_qs = filters_qs.filter(
    Q(
        user__in=[cache.user for cache in caches],
        status_id__in=[Status.Open['id'], Status.Empty['id']],
        revision=0
    ) |
    Q(
        user=None,
        status_id__in=[Status.Open['id'], Status.Empty['id']],
        revision=0
    )
)
```

I used the 'OR' because I'm looking for a result where the query set is either None or in the list. But - it looks not so 'pythonic'... it repeats the same code for minor change. Is there another way? for example, something like - (doesn't work)

```
Q(
  user__in=[cache.user for cache in caches] + [None],
  status_id__in=[
      Status.Open['id'],
      Status.Empty['id']
      ],
  revision=0
  )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why your example is not working, trackback ?

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede - I mean it doesn't get the required result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `isnull` lookup for checking the `None` value. Try this:

```
filters_qs.filter(
    Q(user__in=map(lambda item: item.user, caches)) |
    Q(user__isnull=True),
    status_id__in=[
        Status.Open['id'],
        Status.Empty['id']
    ],
    revision=0
)
```